# snakemake - accessing conda environment assets not in bin/

Tags: snakemake

I am using some conda envs in my workflow which contain useful assets (data, models, etc) that are **not** in the environment bin/ path, e.g. specific files found under share/ , opt/ or other.
Is there a standard way to access these paths from within the workflow? Maybe a variable containing the path to the environment? Otherwise, I'm finding myself using all sorts of Linux tricks to locate these files. Things like:

```
rule snap:
    ...
    conda:
        snap.yaml
    shell:
        """
        # find env dir
        env=`grep -l snap ./.snakemake/conda/*.yaml | xargs basename | sed 's/\.yaml//'`
        snap ./.snakemake/conda/$env/share/HMM/X.hmm {input}
        """
```

Any ideas on how to go about such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$CONDA_PREFIX` contains the path to the current activated environment. From there it should be easy to go to `share`, `opt` etc.

If this doesn't help, try posting the directory tree of your setup and what you want to access as it is not entirely clear, at least to me.